# How do I join multiple glob inputs into a time lapse with ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, timelapse

I'm trying to combine image files from multiple directories into one combined time lapse using ffmpeg, but when running this code, only the first directory is used in the time lapse. How do I combine multiple glob inputs using ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "Time\ Lapse\ 11/*.JPG" \
-pattern_type glob -i "Burst\ Sequence\ 5/*.JPG" \
-pattern_type glob -i "Burst\ Sequence\ 6/*.JPG" \
-r 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p tl11_combined.mp4
```

I've tried using glob sequence which didn't do anything, and I've tried various concat methods using a text file including directory names, but haven't found the correct format so far. Thanks!

Comment: Try surrounding your filenames with single quotes (to hide them from the shell) and removing the backslashes that precede spaces http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion

Comment: Ah so doing that only reads in image files from the first directory and ignores the other 2 folders.